# Replace tf.squeeze using as tf.reshape

Tags: tensorflow, reshape

I need to train a mobile net using tensorflow. The tf.squeeze layer is not supported. Can I replace it with the tf.reshape?

Is the operation:

```
tf.squeeze(net, [1, 2], name='squeeze')
```

the same as:

```
tf.reshape(net, [50,1000], name='reshape')
```

where net has the shape [50,1,1,1000].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you say [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) is not supported? In order to remove 1 dimensional axis from tensor, `tf.squeeze` is the correct operation. But you can achieve your desired work with `tf.reshape` as well though I will suggest you to make use of `tf.squeeze`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am using another sdk for mobile devices which loads tensorflow models but does not support the tf.squeeze layer.

Answer (score 0):

In `tf 2.0` you can easily check that these ops are the same. The only difference that you may remove all axis with `dim == 1` without specifying them. So in the last line you may use `tf.squeeze(x_resh)` instead of `tf.squeeze(x_resh, [1, 2])`.

```
size = [2, 3]
tf.random.set_seed(42)
x = tf.random.normal(size)
x
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3274685, -0.8426258,  0.3194337],
       [-1.4075519, -2.3880599, -1.0392479]], dtype=float32)>

x_resh = tf.reshape(x, [2, 1, 1, 3])
x_resh
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 1, 1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[ 0.3274685, -0.8426258,  0.3194337]]],
       [[[-1.4075519, -2.3880599, -1.0392479]]]], dtype=float32)>

tf.reshape(x_resh, [2, 3])
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3274685, -0.8426258,  0.3194337],
       [-1.4075519, -2.3880599, -1.0392479]], dtype=float32)>

tf.squeeze(x_resh, [1, 2])
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.3274685, -0.8426258,  0.3194337],
       [-1.4075519, -2.3880599, -1.0392479]], dtype=float32)>
```